# Keep the inner div always in the same position of the outer div

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div with a background image that needs to contain it's shape at all times cause of it's odd shape (so it doesn't fall out of sight). In that shape I have a text div that is scrollable vertically. This text block needs to stay in the background shape with 20px margin at all times.

The problem is it scales weird so the text block falls out of the shape.

Here is the code:

```css
.textblock
{
 width: 70%;
    float: left;
    height: 60vh;
}

.text_outer
{
 background-image:url(../img/text_background.png);
 background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-position:right;
 height:100%;
 padding:15px;
}

.text_inner
{
 background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 85%;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 94%;
 overflow:auto;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
    <div class="textblock">
         
        <div class="text_outer">
             
              <div class="text_inner">
                
                 <h2>Title</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sollicitudin ac nisl in commodo. Suspendisse elit dolor, ornare id placerat quis, pretium quis    massa. Morbi magna sapien, convallis at neque eu, mattis scelerisque nulla. Sed eget blandit diam. Ut gravida nibh vitae nunc accumsan tristique. Duis vitae quam eleifend, ultrices eros  nec, viverra ligula. Sed tincidunt luctus congue. Nulla facilisi. Morbi scelerisque, velit sed fermentum pellentesque, massa tortor accumsan libero, vitae suscipit nisi ex id quam. Suspendisse elit elit, maximus at dolor sit amet, vulputate aliquam lacus. Nulla non diam nunc. Duis eget suscipit tortor.
    <br><br>
    Vivamus arcu purus, gravida eu venenatis vitae, pulvinar ac tortor. Mauris quis velit dictum, ultrices justo ut, facilisis ante. Duis convallis feugiat est sed efficitur. Ut id pretium elit. Maecenas venenatis rhoncus porttitor. Fusce dapibus sed arcu vel maximus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed vulputate ornare dolor, eget condimentum ligula pulvinar tincidunt. Vestibulum leo ex, ultricies id sagittis quis, dapibus dapibus odio. Aenean sodales ligula in est posuere auctor. Aliquam tristique elementum pharetra. Integer vitae tortor aliquam, venenatis dolor sit amet, pretium nisi.
                    </p>
                
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood correctly you should using `position absolute` and `relative` for `div`
try like so:

```
 .outer{

  position:Relative;
  background:blue;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:Red;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ngh99ura/4/

Comment: I can't get that to work cause the outer div needs to be responsive at all times so it is made with percentage and vh/vw.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image, but as far as I see you need make background-size: cover in .text-outer and to delete padding in the .text-inner. Something like this:

```
.text_outer
    {
        background-image:url('../img/text_background.png');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position:right;
        height:100%;
        padding:15px;
    }

    .text_inner
    {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 85%;
        float: right;
        height: 94%;
        overflow:auto;
        position:relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes, make your `background-size` as `100% 100%`, you have used padding in both `.textinner` and `.textouter` class and that's why `background-image`, bottom side was not visible.

```css
.textblock
{
 width: 70%;
    float: left;
    height: 60vh;
}

.text_outer
{
 background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
 background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
 background-position:top;
  width:100%;
 height:100%;
 padding:15px;
}

.text_inner
{
 background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 85%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 94%;
 overflow:auto;
 position:relative;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="textblock">
         
        <div class="text_outer">
             
              <div class="text_inner">
                
                 <h2>Title</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sollicitudin ac nisl in commodo. Suspendisse elit dolor, ornare id placerat quis, pretium quis    massa. Morbi magna sapien, convallis at neque eu, mattis scelerisque nulla. Sed eget blandit diam. Ut gravida nibh vitae nunc accumsan tristique. Duis vitae quam eleifend, ultrices eros  nec, viverra ligula. Sed tincidunt luctus congue. Nulla facilisi. Morbi scelerisque, velit sed fermentum pellentesque, massa tortor accumsan libero, vitae suscipit nisi ex id quam. Suspendisse elit elit, maximus at dolor sit amet, vulputate aliquam lacus. Nulla non diam nunc. Duis eget suscipit tortor.
    <br><br>
    Vivamus arcu purus, gravida eu venenatis vitae, pulvinar ac tortor. Mauris quis velit dictum, ultrices justo ut, facilisis ante. Duis convallis feugiat est sed efficitur. Ut id pretium elit. Maecenas venenatis rhoncus porttitor. Fusce dapibus sed arcu vel maximus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed vulputate ornare dolor, eget condimentum ligula pulvinar tincidunt. Vestibulum leo ex, ultricies id sagittis quis, dapibus dapibus odio. Aenean sodales ligula in est posuere auctor. Aliquam tristique elementum pharetra. Integer vitae tortor aliquam, venenatis dolor sit amet, pretium nisi.
                    </p>
                
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
```